# Theme of Flutter app changes only after Hot Restart

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, bloc

I'm trying to implement a feature whose job is to switch beetween light and dark mode using BLoC and SharedPreferences. Through debug prints I know that the DarkModeCubit is working properly. However the MainApp doesn't receive the new state immediately but only after hot restart. I don't know why.

Here is my Main App

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // essential
  await Firebase
      .initializeApp(); // needed for Firebase, included Authentication and Firestore
  //
  // Initialization of all blocs used by most pages
  //
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: ((context) => AuthenticationBloc())),
        BlocProvider(create: ((context) => RefreshUserBloc())),
        BlocProvider(create: ((context) => GetCurrentUserDocCubit())),
        BlocProvider(create: ((context) => DarkModeCubit(PrefsState())))
      ],
      child: MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

//
// Class of the Material App, the top of the widget tree
//
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  final AppRouter _appRouter = AppRouter();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //
    // When the app starts we check if the user is already logged in. If so, we go to the home page, otherwise we go to the login page
    //
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(AuthenticationStarted());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    // Build method of the Material App
    //
    return BlocBuilder<DarkModeCubit, ThemeMode>(
      builder: (context, themeMode) {
        debugPrint('MainApp: $themeMode');
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          //
          //  Theme of the app, with the colorScheme and the textTheme
          //
          theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
          themeMode: themeMode,
          //
          // onGenerateRoute is the chosen routing system. It is defined in the app_router.dart file.
          // When a route is called via Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/routeName'), the onGenerateRoute method is called,
          // and it returns the page associated with the routeName.
          //
          onGenerateRoute: _appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
          //
          //  The initial route is the first route that is shown when the app starts.
          //  It is set to a BlocBuilder that listens to the AuthenticationBloc, and it redirects to the login page if the user is not logged in,
          //  otherwise it redirects to the home page.
          //
          initialRoute: '/',
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Cubit

```
class DarkModeCubit extends Cubit<ThemeMode> {
  final PrefsState prefs;

  DarkModeCubit(this.prefs) : super(ThemeMode.light) {
    _loadTheme();
  }

  ///
  /// Method that loads the current {isDarkTheme}
  ///
  void _loadTheme() async {
    final isDarkTheme = await prefs.getThemePreference();
    emit(isDarkTheme ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light);
  }

  ///
  /// Method that changes the {isDarkTheme}
  ///
  void toggleTheme({required bool isDarkTheme}) async {
    await prefs.setThemePreference(isDarkTheme);
    emit(isDarkTheme ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light);
    debugPrint('DarkModeCubit: $state');
  }

  
}
```

Here is my PrefsState

```
class PrefsState {
  /// Key that stores the location of the dark theme.
  static const _isDarkThemeKey = 'isDarkTheme';

  /// Method that retrieves the bool that indicates whether the theme is dark or light.
  Future<bool> getThemePreference() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(_isDarkThemeKey) ?? false;
  }

  /// Method that set the {isDarkTheme} property in the local storage.
  Future<void> setThemePreference(bool isDarkTheme) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(_isDarkThemeKey, isDarkTheme);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know your AppTheme static valeus but in your first route or widget how is the color being changed when doing hot restart?

Comment: The color is changed the way it should change, but I noticed that the BlocBuilder doesn't receive the new state immediately, but only after hot restart.

My AppTheme values are ThemeDatas with colorScheme and textTheme.

Comment: tested it in dartpad with no problem, isDarkTheme should be false when you're in dark mode to swap to light?

Comment: Yeah, it should be false

Comment: yeah no clue, your code seems fine, and you say that your debugPrint shows your new state but your widget won't listen to that, are you sure you're toggling correctly and what you see when hot restart is not light to dark only because you init your cubit with that and then load it, for example, run getThemePreference in main first and pass that directy to your cubit constructor to pass the initial value

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code it seems that your problem is with how you create the bloc providers in the widget tree:

```
BlocProvider(create: ((context) => DarkModeCubit(PrefsState())))

/// or for readibility:
BlocProvider(
  create: (
    (context) => DarkModeCubit(PrefsState())
  )
)
```

That parenthesis wrapping your `create` make it seems that there is a function within a function, remove it from all your providers so they initialize correctly.

```
BlocProvider(create: (_) => DarkModeCubit(PrefsState()))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem, it persists. Thank you though.

Comment: can you show how .setThemePreference(isDarkTheme) works?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with an easier solution I use it with BLoC

```
 child: BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
      builder: (context, state) => MaterialApp(
        theme: themes[state.theme],
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LocalData.containsKey('opened')
            ? HomeScreen()
            : const OnboardingScreen(),
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generatedRoute,
      ),
    );

    class ThemeInitState extends ThemeState {
     ThemeInitState()
      : super(
            theme: LocalData.getData(key: 'theme') == null
                ? "whiteTheme"
                : LocalData.getData(key: 'theme')!);
}

  class ChangeThemeState extends ThemeState {
     ChangeThemeState({required super.theme});
}
```

themes used in the beginning is a JSON map that contains the Theme objects and I call them based on the key stored in local storage

if you need to view the full code you can check my app source code on GitHub using the following link [Gameaway Source Code](https://github.com/AHMADARBASH/Gameaway)

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] I made a stupid mistake in providing the cubit. It seemed that the Material App and the page where I changed the theme through a switch had two different instances of the DarkModeCubit, so the first was not allowed to listen for state changes.